# Excel - Matching 2 Criteria in Different Rows and Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large export over 20,000 rows from Great Plains.  I can only export to a Tab-Delimited File which isn't the cleanest.  I need a formula I will use on another Worksheet to find the GL code in column B (i.e. 10010-6960-900) and then find the month under that GL (i.e. January) in column A and if both those criteria are met return the value in column D for that month.  Included an image of the export.

The problem is the GL (i.e. 10010-6960-900) only appears once in Column B, then the months. Then the next GL and another set of months. It wouldn't be a problem if the GL repeated next to each month on the export, it would be a simple SUMIFS formula. But I'm having trouble getting Excel to find the GL in Column B, and then the next month that occurs and return the amount.

So in the image below just to be as specific as I can; need the formula to find 10010-6960-900 in column B (yellow highlight), then the month I need in column A (green highlight), and return the value from column D for that month (blue highlight).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
=INDEX(D$9:D$100,MATCH("10010-6960-900",B$9:B$100) + MATCH("January:",A$10:A$21,0)
```

Should do what you describe

Comment: @VBasic2008 quite right, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

## A Double Lookup (Excel Formula)

### Old Office

The formula in cell `H8` of the screenshot below is:

```
=INDEX(INDEX($D$9:$D$34,MATCH($F8,$B$9:$B$34,0)+1):$D$34,
    MATCH($G8,INDEX($A$9:$A$34,MATCH($F8,$B$9:$B$34,0)+1):$A$34,0))
```

Adjust the `34` and the cells `F8` and `G8` or use hard-coded values.

The formulas that lead to the solution are:

```
L8: =B9:B34
M8: =MATCH(F8,B9:B34,0)
N8: =INDEX(A9:A34,MATCH(F8,B9:B34,0)+1)
O8: =INDEX(A9:A34,MATCH(F8,B9:B34,0)+1):A34
P8: =INDEX(D9:D34,MATCH(F8,B9:B34,0)+1):D34
```

Note that they won't spill if you don't have Microsoft 365.

[image]

### Microsoft 365

- The same idea is used in the following formulas. I wanted to see how (if) it could be utilized with the `LET` function and finally with the `LAMBDA` function i.e., there may be better solutions.
- The formulas don't spill, they return a single result i.e. you need to copy them down if you mean to use them as illustrated in the screenshot above.

**`LET`**

```
=LET(Data,$A$9:$D$34,lVal,$F8,lValBelow,$G8,lCol,2,lColBelow,1,rColBelow,4,lrOffset,1,
    lData,INDEX(Data,,lCol),lDataB,INDEX(Data,,lColBelow),rDataB,INDEX(Data,,rColBelow),
    lrIndex,XMATCH(lVal,lData)+lrOffset,
    lResult,INDEX(lDataB,lrIndex):TAKE(lDataB,-1),rResult,INDEX(rDataB,lrIndex):TAKE(rDataB,-1),
XLOOKUP(lValBelow,lResult,rResult,""))
```

**`LAMBDA`**

```
=LAMBDA(Data,lVal,lValBelow,lCol,lColBelow,rColBelow,[lRowOffset],LET(
    lData,INDEX(Data,,lCol),lDataB,INDEX(Data,,lColBelow),rDataB,INDEX(Data,,rColBelow),
    lrOffset,IF(ISOMITTED(lRowOffset),1,lRowOffset),lrIndex,XMATCH(lVal,lData)+lrOffset,
    lResult,INDEX(lDataB,lrIndex):TAKE(lDataB,-1),rResult,INDEX(rDataB,lrIndex):TAKE(rDataB,-1),
XLOOKUP(lValBelow,lResult,rResult,"")))($A$9:$D$34,$F10,$G10,2,1,4,1)
```

**Function (Defined Name)**

You can create a function (`DoubleLookup`) by assigning the following formula to a name
(`Formulas->Name Manager->New`):

```
=LAMBDA(Data,lVal,lValBelow,lCol,lColBelow,rColBelow,[lRowOffset],LET(
    lData,INDEX(Data,,lCol),lDataB,INDEX(Data,,lColBelow),rDataB,INDEX(Data,,rColBelow),
    lrOffset,IF(ISOMITTED(lRowOffset),1,lRowOffset),lrIndex,XMATCH(lVal,lData)+lrOffset,
    lResult,INDEX(lDataB,lrIndex):TAKE(lDataB,-1),rResult,INDEX(rDataB,lrIndex):TAKE(rDataB,-1),
XLOOKUP(lValBelow,lResult,rResult,"")))
```

Then you can use the function in the workbook with various parameters using the following:

```
=DoubleLookup($A$9:$D$34,$F8,$G8,2,1,4,1)
```

- Note that the last parameter (`lRowOffset`) is optional and equal to `1` by default so you can omit it. The parameter designates the offset between the row of the 1st match and the starting row of the range where to look for the 2nd match.